# Unable to access Sonarqube Server configured on Virtual machine on Azure Cloud from other machines?

Tags: c#, azure, virtual-machine, sonarqube

Sonarqube (for C# project) is configured using SQL 2014 on Microsoft's azure cloud virtual machine. I'm trying to access it from my machine, but "This webpage is not available" message comes up on the browser screen.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Is `sonar.web.context` configured on this server? Do you have a reverse proxy in front of SonarQube? Are the required ports (9000 for a default installation, 80 if you have a reverse proxy, 443 if you have an HTTPS reverse proxy) accessible on the VM?

Answer (score 2):

Two things you'll need to do. The first is to allow the connection in the Windows Firewall (if you're running that). So, add a new TCP rule for the port you have the server running on (often 9000).

Second, you need to configure an Endpoint for your virtual machine in the Azure portal.  Do this by entering the  manage.windowsazure.com portal and navigating to your virtual machine instance. Click on the ENDPOINTS tab, and then the Add button in the bottom toolbar.  I created a stand-alone endpoint, then gave it a Name of SonarQube Web, Protocol is TCP, Public and Private ports are 9000.